# Как задать фиксированный отступ bottom 50px снизу от viewport'а

Tags: jquery, вёрстка, html5, css3

Как задать фиксированный отступ `bottom 50px` снизу от *viewport*-а (именно от него), если родительский блок элемента по высоте больше чем *viewport*, т.е. по высоте есть *скролл*?

`position fixed` не подходит: элемент должен оставаться в родительском блоке, т.е. уходить вверх при прокрутке сайта.

Answer (score 2):

Так годится?

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 200%;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  line-height: 2em;
  top: calc(100vh - 50px - 2em);
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div>Block in the bottom</div>
```

Comment: Проще написать `bottom: 50px;` чем формулу рисовать `top: calc(100vh - 50px - 2em);`.

Comment: @Visman, `bottom:50px` будет отсчитываться от нижнего края, я не от низа окна, поэтому не подходит. `calc` при желании (и высоте в пикселях) можно заменить на margin.